# How to run EOS nodeos in Testnet?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, testnet

How can I run EOS node in testnet mode to test my transaction for wallet and mange my contracts like Koven testnet in Ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 test nets for EOS, [Jungle](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/) and [Kylin](https://www.cryptokylin.io/).

Once on their web site, register and get some tokens from their faucet and follow instructions to deploy your smart contract.